# Blender Mantaflow - Simulation has some weird failures that I can't get under control

Tags: mantaflow

I´ve tried around with some mantaflow sim with different domains and particle emitting smoke/fire simulation. So far the stuff looks great but I have two issues all the time that I can´t control.

1. Even though they are collider objects, the fire hit through this surfaces at a certain time of the simulation. Seems to be always the same frame/progress of the simulation.

[image: scene showing fire passing through surface]

During the first frames it stays below the collider (boosters) but then it doesn't. I've tried even a special plane that should just block the fire for rising up, but without any success. Looks like some voxels have too much energy and ignore everything, just punching ultra fast to the top. The fire is emitted by particles with a high velocity to the bottom.

2. The smoke tower looks nice but at the bottom it starts to become cubic during the progress of the simulation.

[image: scene showing the smoke becoming blocky]

I would appreciate any hints or tips for fixing this in my sim.

---

Here is an additional picture showing problem no. 1 better.

[image: Second version showing colliders being ignored]

Comment: For the 1st problem, it is not quite certain what it can be, it may be due to way too small domain resolution, did you tried to lower it? If yes and it is not the problem, it may be margin/thickness of those colliders or smoke

Comment: For the 2nd problem,.. are you using adaptive domain?

Comment: for 1. yes i tried and turned the resolution in both directions. only result is with higher res the smoke is less dens beacause the particle amount stays the same.  for 2. ive tried with adaptive and without. both the same result. tried baking complete including noise in one step, tried baking seperately.

Comment: There are often problems with the Collision Effector properties (not the Resolution in the Domain properties, so the Booster or Rocket mesh modifier).  I at least find with Fluid that an Effector Collision Thickness of less then 0.5 is ignored.  So try a setting of 0.5 on these.  I consider this to be a bug in the product.